# Phantom file in github commit

Tags: git

I am trying to push some changes to my github repository but the push is failing because of a large file that git thinks is in the repository.

```
remote: Error code: 38865a38ccad9b1d9f394c35344906e6
remote: warning: Error GH413: Large files detected.
remote: warning: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File videos/Lecture2.mp4 is 134.01 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
```

But the file videos/Lecture2.mp4 is not in the repository. There is no videos directory either.

Any ideas of how to remove this file so that I can push the other changes?

Comment: How are you so sure it isn't in the repository?

Comment: Does the file exist anywhere in your history? It doesn't have to exist in the current state of the working copy for Git to want to push it, it just has to have existed once in your history, then it will still be in your repo, even if you delete it from the current state of your code in the most recent commit.

Comment: If you do `git log --oneline --name-status --patch`, and then type `/Lecture2.mp4` in the `less` pager, do you see the file show up in your commit history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that file was committed at any point in the history of the git repo, but then deleted, you wouldn't see it in your current status, but it would still be pushed.

Give BFG a try to remove that large file from your history.

[BFG Repo-Cleaner](http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/): "Removes large or troublesome blobs like git-filter-branch does, but faster."

Comment: Probably easier to do `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD`

Comment: @nishantjr easier than `bfg --delete-files filename my-repo.git`? And `bfg` is way faster than `git filter-branch`.

Comment: Can confirm bfg is better. While I prefer the simplicity of copying and pasting @nishantjr's command to fix my big-file-now-deleted-but-stil-choking-`$git push` problem, it just doesn't work. Downloading, installing bfg and using java from my git shell seems like a lot of work but it did the trick.

Comment: Without downloading software, what is the best way to do this?  When I run the "git filter-branch..." command above I get this error: "You need to run this command from the toplevel of the working tree."