# Can I work with my repository during git filter-branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

I checked in some big binary files into a git repository. I noticed it got very slow. Up to 4-5 seconds to respond to a `git status .` in the root directory. So I decided to clean the repository with `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -f web/libs/*.*jar" HEAD` and similar commands. But they take up to hours to complete.

Can I still work with my repository, while those commands are running?

Comment: Did you try BFG? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18525768/6309) It is supposed to be quicker.

Comment: @Cupcake Can you provide the link for the question, which this is a duplicate of?

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes I'll have to find one later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Don't try to work in your repository during a filter-branch

You could *possibly* continue working in your repo during a filter-branch by sending the filter-branch process into the background of your shell session, or open another terminal and continue working with your repo that way, **but I highly recommend against that, you could cause a lot of problems in your repo if you tried.**

Then again, Git might lock certain files during a filter-branch (such as the index), so it might throw a bunch of errors if you tried non-filter-branch operations during a filter-branch anyways.

### Solution 1: use index-filter

Don't use a tree-filter for this, as you've seen, it's very slow, because it has to checkout each commit into the working copy. Use an index-filter instead, as [recommended in the filter-branch documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html), because it doesn't need to checkout each commit, so it thus runs faster:

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter '
  git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch web/libs/*.*jar
' HEAD
```

You can also speed up the filter-branch by passing a range of commits leading to HEAD, instead of filtering all of the commits. For example, the following will filter the last 20 or 21 commits:

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter '
  git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch web/libs/*.*jar
' HEAD~20..HEAD
```

#### Documentation

[The options](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_options):

> ```
> --index-filter <command>
> ```
>
> This is the filter for rewriting the index. It is similar to the tree filter but does not check out the tree, which makes it much faster. Frequently used with `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ...`, see EXAMPLES below. For hairy cases, see [git-update-index(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html).

[The example](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-filter-branch.html#_examples):

> Using `--index-filter` with `git rm` yields a significantly faster version. Like with using `rm filename`, `git rm --cached filename` will fail if the file is absent from the tree of a commit. If you want to "completely forget" a file, it does not matter when it entered history, so we also add `--ignore-unmatch`:
>
> ```bash
> git filter-branch --index-filter '
>   git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename
> ' HEAD
> ```

### Solution 2: use BFG

Or you could try using the BFG tool, [as VonC recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446607/can-i-work-with-my-repository-during-git-filter-branch/24446976#comment37828648_24446607).

Answer (score 2):

Speed is your problem here, and I wrote the [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to be faster. Instead of several hours, it'll almost certainly finish in less than half a minute.

You should carefully follow the [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage), but the core part is just this:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-files *.jar my-repo.git
```

This will delete all jars in your repository history that you aren't currently using in your latest commit.

The BFG is typically at least [10-50x](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsR1d5Zpes8HdER3VGU1a3dOcmVHMmtzT2dsS2xNenc#gid=0) faster than running `git filter-branch`, and generally easier to use. If you're determined to use `git filter-branch`, you might want to see this SO answer I wrote a while back about how to make it go a little faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16154016/438886

Whether you use `git filter-branch` or the BFG, you really *shouldn't* work on the repository while the history is getting rewritten - however, with the BFG, that period of time will be only a few seconds.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: I did not know this because I've been staring at the old kernel.org version of the documentation for so long, but the [up-to-date version of the Git manuals actually endorse the BFG Repo Cleaner](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)! That's cool! Congratulations!